# download href no longer work on the popover page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

It seems that the download link on the popover page no longer work.
I had a chrome extension, if I click a download link on the popover page, for example:

```
<a download="test.txt" href="data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8,testtest1234567!@#$%^&*()_+\00">Click me</a>
```

Chrome will download the text file to the default download folder.

But about two months ago, I found this approach no longer work, and Chrome does not give any error message either in the extension background page or the popover page itself.

If you open the extension popover page in a tab, then the download link works.

Firefox 59 works fine now

Edge never work (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8477778/)

My current solution is opening a new tab to save the file, but it is not what I expected. Do you have any solutions on this?

Thank you very much

Comment: Use the workaround in comment2 in https://crbug.com/821219. The bug is fixed in Chrome 66.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm, tested on Chrome 66, works fine.